# Height rendering bug in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, height, rendering

I have the following page...

http://jsfiddle.net/8JxkW/4/

It consists of 3 toolbar controls. However I have stripped the page down to the bare minimum to localise the issue I'm having.

When rendered in IE9 standards mode each toolbar correctly renders with a height of 26px. This is also true in Chrome.

However in IE8 standards mode, the 2nd toolbar renders with a height of 27px. It is strange that both the IE dev tools and jQuery indicate that the 3 toolbars are of equal height. However if you examine them closely in a graphics program you will see that the 2nd toolbar has 1px extra in height.

**Can I put this simply down to being an IE8 rendering bug?** And if so, how can I workaround it?

Comment: I like the fact that you're supporting IE6 (with the star hack and the `zoom:1`) and Firefox 2 (with `-moz-inline-box` etc) in the CSS in your fiddle, but perhaps the time has come to drop those browsers. More seriously, it's possible that the `zoom:1` might be having an effect on later versions of IE that don't need the hack (IE8); see what happens if you take them out.

Comment: I would love to be able to drop support for those browsers! Unfortunately that's out of my hands for the time being. Taking the zoom:1 out had no effect but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would putting a `max-height:26px;` on the toolbar keep it from going over?

Comment: Thanks, this keeps all 3 toolbars restricted to 26px.